# Cannot find the CAPTCHA on the Human-Verification page

Tags: bug, captcha

I'm in China now.When I turn to the Human Verification  page there is no place to filling the CAPTCHA and I can't find the CAPTCHA either. The picture only shows the sentence like ……study ……  he is ……，no capital word there.Since my reputation is not enough,I can't add the picture here to make it more clear.Must I use VPN?
[image]

Comment: add a link to a screenshot if you can please..

Comment: Interesting possible cause: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/recaptcha/Nm469kX7rRo

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks, I will see the page later.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA My reputation is not enough now